# How to write $a|b \wedge ((a=0 \wedge b=0) \vee (a\ne0 \wedge b\ne0))$

Tags: logic, proof-writing

How can I write the expression

$$a|b \wedge ((a=0 \wedge b=0) \vee (a\ne0 \wedge b\ne0))$$

concisely and clearly in English? A direct translation yields

> $a$ divides $b$ and either {$a$ and $b$ are both zero} or {$a$ and $b$ are both nonzero},

but it seems like there should be a shorter way to say that. Also, that wording is unclear without the brackets.

The following is shorter, but is still unclear without brackets:

> $a$ divides $b$ and {$a=0$ if and only if $b=0$}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fact that $a \wedge (b \vee c) \iff (a \wedge b) \vee (a \wedge c)$:

Either $a|b$ and $a = b = 0$, or $a|b$ and $a, b \neq 0$. Notice how the use of the word 'either' gets the reader in the mindset that they need to wait for at least two possibilities. Hope this helps a little!

Edit: got rid of some useless stuff.

Comment: Hm, "$a|b$ and either $a=b=0$ or $a,b\ne0$" actually looks okay. I guess I really just needed to shorten the zero/nonzero parts to make the emphasis clear. Thanks for the inspiration!

Answer (score 0):

$a\mid b \land ((a=0 \land b=0)\lor(a\neq 0 \land b\neq 0))$

This reads: "'a' divides 'b' and either both are zero or neither is zero."

Answer (score 0):

Either $\frac{b}{a}$ is a non zero integer or both are zero.